# override angular typechecking

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I'm using [`@angular-builders/custom-webpack`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@angular-builders/custom-webpack) for customization of `ng serve`'s webpack configs.

What I'm trying to do is replace angular's mechanism of `.ts` loading to only transpile, not type check.

But, angular does a lot of "magic" with these files, which I don't want to break.

Any ideas how to go about it?
sadly there's no more `ng eject`, so I don't know of an easy way to follow how angular handles `.ts` files.